# Hide mounted volume icon on the desktop?

Tags: 10.10, nautilus

I have a 10.10 installation. `/etc/fstab` mounts a partition to `~/Desktop` and my desktop icons work fine. However mounted volume icon always appears on Desktop.
Altough I have unchecked `volumes_visible` option in `gconf-editor`, still icon is shown.
Is there a change in 10.10 ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake; I was running gconf-editor as su, so it was changing root's configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run >> gconf-editor

1. goto apps->nautilus->desktop
2. Uncheck the option: "volume visible"

and after that all the mounted volumes will removed from your desktop.

Comment: hi, as i mentioned already tried that :(

Comment: It works here in 11.04 alpha2 just checked

Comment: Hi Paul,I am 110% sure It will work any version of the ubuntu. Pls just check if you are following the steps properly.